# install GSL 2.6

Tags: gnu

I had GSL 2.3 installed on my pc for along time now. I tried to update to 2.6 following [this](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/)
but when I check the version using gsl-config --version, it says that I have 2.3. Is there a step that I missed?

I missed to use gsl-config --prefix to find the path and use that in the ./configure step, instead of setting --prefix to what the post suggests.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: In the step `./configure --prefix=/home/yourname/gsl` did you choose the same location as for the previous installation, or a different one? is the new location before any old location in your `PATH`?

Comment: Why not use the gsl from official repos `sudo apt install libgsl-dev`